# Download filename in pre-authorized Object Storage instead of storage id (guid) in Pre-Authenticated Request

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Is there a way to change the download name when calling a pre-authorized request url in oci object storage?  Currently it uses the name of the storage object id when it downloads the object to the local disk.  I want to use the opc-meta-filename instead.

Comment: Previously we used Swift Object Storage and their API for getting a pre-authorized request url had the ability to pass the filename as a querystring parameter.  We were hoping to have the same functionality on OCI

Comment: How are you downloading the object? Are you using the browser?

Answer (score 0):

We wont be able to change the object storage name, When you upload objects, you can provide optional response headers and user-defined metadata. Response headers are HTTP headers sent from Object Storage to Object Storage clients when objects are downloaded, so we wont be able to modify it.